# Tkinter, AttributeError: "PhotoImage" Object has no attribute '_last_child_ids'

Tags: python, tkinter

In this code, I'm basically making a GUI for a quizzing App, with a true and false image as a  button (a check and a cross) and I'm also following carefully as this code is from a Udemy course that I'm taking. For Some reason, the instructor can run the GUI Code just fine, but when I do it, I get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Armand S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2538, in _setup
    if master._last_child_ids is None:
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_last_child_ids'
```

Now, Here's the code in question:

```
 true_image = PhotoImage(file ="true.png")
 self.true_button = Button(true_image, highlightthickness=0)
 self.true_button.grid(row = 2, column = 8)
    
 false_image = PhotoImage(file = "false.png")   
 self.false_button = Button(image = false_image, highlightthickness=0)
 self.false_button.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
```

I seriously have no idea what the solution is, I've tried using PIL, with the PhotoImageTk function, like this:

```
im_true = PIL.Image.open("true.png")
true_image = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(im_true)
im_false = PIL.Image.open("false.png")
false_image = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(im_false)
```

But it's still giving me a whole error. No Idea what to do.

Comment: Notice how one of your Buttons uses a `image=` parameter to specify the picture, and the other one just uses an unnamed (positional) parameter for the picture?  That's the error right there. The first positional parameter to any Tkinter widget is the parent widget, which cannot be an image.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned by @ jasonharper.

In your case. Don't used `highlightthickness=0` for both images. The Button must used keyword `image=`

Your code:

```
self.true_image = PhotoImage(file ="NOKIA.png")
self.true_button = Button( image=true_image)
self.true_button.grid(row = 2, column = 8)

false_image = PhotoImage(file = "supra-logo.png")   
self.false_button = Button(image = false_image)
self.false_button.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
```

As for me w/out using instantiated.
Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

true_image = tk.PhotoImage(file ="NOKIA.png")
true_button = tk.Button( image=true_image)
true_button.grid(row = 2, column = 8)

false_image = tk.PhotoImage(file = "supra-logo.png")   
false_button = tk.Button(image = false_image)
false_button.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

 
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]